# Parse Apache VHosts to get list of Domains and Folder Paths

Tags: php, apache, vhosts

Given a path X or a copy of the apache vhosts configuration file, how would I parse that file using PHP?

E.g. Given a variable containing a string that has the contents of an Apache vhosts configuration, how would I get a list of hosted domains/subdomains alias?

For example, given:

```
#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *:80



<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin contact@tomjn.com
    DocumentRoot "/srv/www/localhost/

    ServerName 127.0.0.1
    ServerAlias localhost
    CustomLog "/srv/www/logs/localhost-access_log.log" combined
    ErrorLog "/srv/www/logs/localhost-error_log.log"

    <Directory "/srv/www/localhost">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin contact@tomjn.com
    DocumentRoot "/srv/www/2.7.localhost.com/

    ServerName 2.7.localhost.com
    ServerAlias 2.7.localhost.com
    CustomLog "/srv/www/logs/2.7.localhost.com-access_log.log" combined
    ErrorLog "/srv/www/logs/2.7.localhost.com-error_log.log"

    <Directory "/srv/www/2.7.localhost.com">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

How would I get this output:

- localhost
- 2.7.localhost.com

Here's something very close written in Python:

http://www.poldylicious.de/system/files/apacheconfig.py.txt

Comment: from a quick search i didn't see any php library that already do this... you might have to just parse it yourself.  THe quick search did yield a python library  http://www.poldylicious.de/system/files/apacheconfig.py.txt

Comment: hmmm this is being flagged as a duplicate yet i cant find such a duplicate?

Comment: hmm that isn't a duplicate, and it doesn't answer my question either. That guy wants to find the error log, I don't. The answer doesn't give me what I need either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmmm the answer this was based on has dissapeared/got deleted, for whatever reason, here's my finalised version of it:

```
<?php
function return_server_alias($fileName){
    $file = fopen($fileName,'r');
    $servers = array();
    while(!feof($file)) { 
        $line = fgets($file);
        // STRIP WHITE SPACE HERE
        $line = trim($line);
        // CHECK IF STRING BEGINS WITH ServerAlias
        $tokens = explode(' ',$line);
        if(!empty($tokens)){
            if(strtolower($tokens[0]) == 'serveralias'){
                $servers[] = $tokens[1];
            }
        }
    }
    fclose($file);
    return $servers;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
# Get Vhosts files
$path       = '/etc/apache2/sites-enabled'; # change to suit your needs
$a_directory = scandir($path);
$a_conf_files = array_diff($a_directory, array('..', '.'));
$info = array(); $x=0;

foreach($a_conf_files as $conf_file){
 $Thisfile   = fopen($path .'/'.$conf_file, 'r')or die('No open ups..');

    while(!feof($Thisfile)){
        $line = fgets($Thisfile);
        $line = trim($line);

       // CHECK IF STRING BEGINS WITH ServerAlias
        $tokens = explode(' ',$line);

        if(!empty($tokens)){
            if(strtolower($tokens[0]) == 'servername'){
                $info[$x]['ServerName'] = $tokens[1];
            }
            if(strtolower($tokens[0]) == 'documentroot'){
                $info[$x]['DocumentRoot'] = $tokens[1];
            }
            if(strtolower($tokens[0]) == 'errorlog'){
                $info[$x]['ErrorLog'] = $tokens[1];
            }
            if(strtolower($tokens[0]) == 'serveralias'){
                $info[$x]['ServerAlias'] = $tokens[1];
            }

        }else{
            echo "Puked...";
        }
    }

fclose($file);
$x++;
}

print_r($info);
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ServerName] => bootstrap
            [ServerAlias] => BootstrapProject
            [DocumentRoot] => /data/sites/bootstrap/htdocs
            [ErrorLog] => /data/sites/bootstrap/log/error.log
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ServerName] => localhost
            [ServerAlias] => dfs
            [DocumentRoot] => /data/sites/scott/htdocs
            [ErrorLog] => /data/sites/scott/log/error.log
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ServerName] => wordpress
            [ServerAlias] => wordpress
            [DocumentRoot] => /data/sites/wordpress/public_html
            [ErrorLog] => /data/sites/wordpress/log/error.log
        )

)
```

Comment: Adapted his answer above, and posted my final code, to display how it is output for dissemination.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I found, there is no such library available. If you want a simple solution, you could just use regexes to find all virtual hosts, and use regexes on that to find all the variables and their values. Though you should take care with things like `<Directory>` inside vhost definitions.

Answer (score -1):

Here's my rework to get more informations from yours vhosts:

```
<pre><?php

    # Get Vhosts files
    $path       = '/etc/apache2/sites-enabled'; # change to suit your needs
    $a_directory = scandir($path);
    $a_conf_files = array_diff($a_directory, array('..', '.'));
    $info = array(); $x=0;`enter code here`

    foreach($a_conf_files as $conf_file){
     $Thisfile   = fopen($path .'/'.$conf_file, 'r')or die('No open ups..');

        $info[$x]['VHostFile'] = $conf_file;
        while(!feof($Thisfile)){
            $tokens = array();
            $line = fgets($Thisfile);
            $line = trim($line);

            if(preg_match('/\s*#+.*/',$line))
                $info[$x]['Commentaires'][] = $line;
            else
    {


            if(count($tokens)==3){
                if(strtolower($tokens[1]) == 'servername'){
                    $info[$x]['ServerName'][] = $tokens[2];
                    $index[$tokens[2]] = $x;
                }
                elseif(strtolower($tokens[1]) == 'documentroot'){
                    $info[$x]['DocumentRoot'] = $tokens[2];
                }
                elseif(strtolower($tokens[1]) == 'errorlog'){
                    $info[$x]['ErrorLog'] = $tokens[2];
                }
                elseif(strtolower($tokens[1]) == 'serveralias'){
                    $info[$x]['ServerAlias'][] = $tokens[2];
                }
                elseif(strtolower($tokens[1]) == 'virtualhost'){
                    $info[$x]['VirtualHost'] = $tokens[2];
                }
                elseif(strtolower($tokens[1]) == 'loglevel'){
                    $info[$x]['LogLevel'] = $tokens[2];
                }
                elseif(strtolower($tokens[1]) == 'assignuserid'){
                    $info[$x]['AssignUserId'] = $tokens[2];
                }
                elseif(strtolower($tokens[1]) == 'ifmodule'){
                    $info[$x]['IfModule'][] = $tokens[2];
                }
                elseif(strtolower($tokens[1]) == 'directory'){
                    $info[$x]['Directory'][] = $tokens[2];
                }
                elseif(strtolower($tokens[1]) == 'serveradmin'){
                    $info[$x]['ServerAdmin'] = $tokens[2];
                }
                elseif(strtolower($tokens[1]) == 'options'){
                    $info[$x]['Options'] = $tokens[2];
                }
                elseif(strtolower($tokens[1]) == 'indexoptions'){
                    $info[$x]['IndexOptions'] = $tokens[2];
                }
                elseif(strtolower($tokens[1]) == 'alias'){
                    $info[$x]['Alias'][] = $tokens[2];
                }
                elseif(!empty($tokens[1]))
                    $info[$x]['Autre'][$tokens[1]] = $tokens[2];

            }elseif(!empty($line)){
                $info[$x]['Illisible'][] = $line;
            }
    }
        }

    fclose($Thisfile);
    $x++;
    }

    echo var_export($index,true);

    echo var_export($info,true);

?></pre>
```